# Can't create view using a role

Tags: oracle-12c, role

I am learning **Oracle** and have to do roles. I created an `c##admin` from a sys, granted him all grants. Then I created a `c##manager_role` and `c##manager`. I granted this role to `c##manager`. After that I started to grant privileges to `c##manager_role`. In addition I granted the following:

```
CREATE VIEW                              YES YES NO

CREATE ANY VIEW                          NO  NO  NO

DROP ANY VIEW                            YES YES NO
```

Above output from:

```
select * from role_sys_privs where ROLE = 'C##MANAGER_ROLE' order by 1;
```

Now, I can't understand, why `CREATE ANY VIEW` has 3 "NO" and why I can't create any view from `c##manager`.

From c##admin:

```
grant CREATE ANY VIEW TO c##manager_role with admin option CONTAINER=all;
```

From c##manager:

```
create view friends_v4 as select t1.nickname as "USER", t2.nickname as "FRIEND" from c##admin.clients t1, c##admin.clients t2, c##admin.friends where (t1.id = c##admin.friends.user_id and t2.id = c##admin.friends.friend_id);
```

Error:

> Error report -
> ORA-01031: привилегий недостаточно
> 01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
>
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
> the necessary privileges.
>
> *Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
> administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

All tables noted exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to *create* a view is not [quite] enough.

The Owner [account] of the finished View must have *read privileges* on the Tables used by that view.  These privileges *cannot* be conferred through any Role.

```
grant read on friends to owner_of_friends_v4 ; 
grant read on clients to owner_of_friends_v4 ;
```

Also, why are you working with Common users here (starting "C##")?

I would only expect to see these in the Container database, not any of the Pluggable ones that live within it (which is where I would expect to see all Application Tables and Data).